# How can I pass an index variable from Angular 5's ngFor to a component method?

Tags: angular5

I have a list of images that I'm looping over and displaying in the browser. Each image has a click handler which only accepts one argument - the image's index. The problem is, I can't quite figure out how to pass that index to the method.

```
<img *ngFor="let img of images; let i = index"src="{{img}}" alt="{{i}}"   
(click)="doSomething({{i}})">
```

I'd like to be able to pass that 'i' into the doSomething() method but I can't quite figure out how to without getting an error. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the template braces - the `(click)` event callback is just plain JS so you can call:

```
(click)='doSomething(i)'
```

Comment: I thought the solution would be complicated or something but that worked perfectly lol. I'm laughing because I'm like "Why didn't I think of that?" Thank you so much.